# Redux Saga wait for action creator that makes an api call

Tags: javascript, redux-saga

I have an action creator which is being watched like this:

```
yield takeLatest('actionCreator', actionFlow);
```

in file X.

Inside action flow there's an api call and another dispatch to store this data into the store.

Then, from file Y, I have a saga, and I want to call this `actionCreator`.
So I go:

```
yield put({ type: 'actionCreator', etc.. });
```

However, after this, I do `yield select(selector)` where selector selects this data and it returns null (as it was before the api call.

Is there a way to wait for that "`actionFlow`" to end?

File X:

```
export const aCreator= ({ data, type }) => ({
    type: ACTION_A,
    payload: { data, type },
}); 


function* aFlow() {
   //api call
   //put
}

export default function*() {
    yield takeLatest(ACTION_A, aFlow);
}
```

File Y

```
import { aCreator } from 'fileX';

function* bFlow(){
    yield put(aCreator({ data }));

    const something = yield select(selector); //this should return the data saved in the reducer by aFlow but return null, as if it didn't wait for aFlow to finish.
}

export default function*() {
    yield takeLatest(ACTION_B, bFlow);
}
```

Comment: We will need some code.

Comment: @kinduser I added some example code

Answer (score 0):

`put` is non blocking so it won't wait until the `aFlow` has finished.

```
function* bFlow() {
   yield put(aCreator({ data }));

   const something = yield select(selector); // this will happen immediately
}
```

You could add a `take` effect before `select`, so it will wait until the call from `aFlow` finished.

```
function* bFlow() {
   yield put(aCreator({ data }));
   yield take(dispatched action from aFlow after api call);

   const something = yield select(selector); // will wait until aFlow finishes
}
```

The dispatched action can be actually anything:

```
function* aFlow() {
   //api call
   //put
   yield put('api_finished');
}

function* bFlow() {
   yield put(aCreator({ data }));
   yield take('api_finished');

   const something = yield select(selector); // will wait until aFlow finishes
}
```

Comment: what do you mean dispatched action from aFlow after api call? There are multiple "puts" depending on what the api returned...

Comment: @nick then listen to them in your `bFlow` function. Or you can either create some random action that will determine if api call finished - see updated answer.